# Can't connect to Win server 2016 remotely from specific devices, (this computer can't connect to the remote computer)

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, windows-10

We have an online Windows server 2016 that we connect to from several locations(from outside and inside the office)remotely using the native remote desktop software in our machines, we are using windows 10 with latest updates and every thing is just working fine.

When I try to connect to the server from my home, it wouldn't connect at all, I have tried several machines (physical and virtual)with several windows 10 versions(pro~enterprise) and I always get one of two massages

> This computer can't connect to the remote computer. Try to connecting
>   again. if the problem .....

or

> An internal error occurred ....

The remote desktop window always stuck at "Configuring remote session..." before giving the error messages

I made sure the RDP port is opened from my side to the server by using

```
Telnet server_ip 3389
```

This issue only happens to me but not to my colleagues, they can connect from their homes and even from other countries!
I have a private (connected directly to the DSL router without anyone else) DSL connection to my house by the way.
I have tried a lot of solutions, wasted a lot of time trying to fix this issue but failed!

Comment: Ask your ISP if they block specific services/ports.

Comment: What exactly could be blocked, I did as I mentioned a telnet test and it passed!

Comment: For example UDP Port 3389, which you also need.

Comment: Do you know how to test for that?

Answer (score -1):

**Delete the Saved Credentials**

1. Open up the Remote Desktop Connection application.
2. Click on ‘Show options’ and then navigate to the Advanced tab.
3. Under ‘Connect from anywhere’, click Settings
4. Afterward, click on Delete credentials to remove them.

**Delete Credentials Using Control Panel**

5. Go to the Start Menu and open up the Control Panel.
6. Now, navigate to Credential Manager and then click on Windows
   Credentials.
7. From the list, remove the credentials for RDP.
8. Launch Remote Desktop Connection again and see if it works.

**Using the Group Policies**

9. Press Windows Key + R to open Run.
10. Type in ‘gpedit.msc’ and press Enter.
11. Navigate to the following location:

    Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Security
12. From the list of policies, double-click ‘Require use of specific
     security layer for remote (RDP) connections’.
13. Click the Enabled box and then from the drop-down list in front of
     the Security layer, choose Negotiate.
14. Hit Apply and then click OK.
15. Restart your system for it to take effect.

**Modifying Windows Firewall Settings**

16. Go to the Start Menu, search ‘Allow an app through Windows
     Firewall’ and open it up.
17. Click on Change Settings to be able to add an exception.
18. Locate Remote Desktop and make sure the box is ticked

**Checking Remote Connections**

19. Go to the Start Menu, type in ‘Remote settings’ and select ‘Allow
     remote access to your computer’.
20. Make sure that the ‘Allow Remote Assistance connections to this
     computer’ box is checked
21. Click Apply and then hit OK.
22. Try using RDP now.

> Note: Let me know if you are still unable to connect

Comment: Nothing really worked at all!